# sql trigger not working/ERROR ORA-00911

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, database-trigger, ora-00911

have problem with sql trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_zapujceni
AFTER INSERT
ON VYPUJCIT
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE TITUL t
set t.POCET_AKTUALNE = t.POCET_AKTUALNE – 1
where t.ID_TITUL = :new.ID_TITUL;
END;
```

where line `AFTER INSERT` says ERROR: SQL Statement Ignored and line `ON VYPUJCIT` says: ORA-00911: Invalid character

does anyone knows and solution? Thanks a lot, I am not a sql master

Comment: when adding set t.POCET_AKTUALNE = 2 works without problem

Comment: Is POCET_AKTUALNE is type of numeric?

Comment: Can you provide the table structure also for VYPUJCIT, TITUL

Answer (score 3):

Your minus sign is some Unicode character but no "regular" minus sign.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ec90fed64bee6d3cd01af29bc91a89dc)

Just replace the Unicode minus sign with a "regular" one and your trigger will be OK.

Comment: +1 - copying the code from the question and running it through dump also shows it as `e2,80,93`, which is [an en-dash](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm).